Issues with LaTeX Formatting in Matplotlib
I'm trying to display LaTeX formulas using Matplotlib in Python. I have two pieces of code, one of which works correctly, while the other raises a ValueError.
Here’s the code that works:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Set the LaTeX formula
formula = r"$L_0(x)=x \quad ; \quad L_n(x)=L_{n-1}^2-2 \quad \forall n \geq 1$"

# Create a figure and an axis to display the formula
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 1))
ax.text(0.5, 0.5, formula, fontsize=20, ha='center', va='center')
ax.axis('off')  # Remove axes to show only the formula

# Save as SVG
plt.savefig("formula.svg", format="svg")
plt.show()

This code produces the desired output. However, when I run this other code:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Set the LaTeX formula
formula = r"$L_n= \begin{cases}4 & \text { if } n=0 \\ L_{n-1}^2-2 & \text { otherwise }\end{cases}$"

# Create a figure and an axis to display the formula
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 1))
ax.text(0.5, 0.5, formula, fontsize=20, ha='center', va='center')
ax.axis('off')  # Remove axes to show only the formula

# Save as SVG
plt.savefig("formula.svg", format="svg")
plt.show()

I receive the following error:
ValueError: 
L_n= \begin{cases}4 & \text { if } n=0 \\ L_{n-1}^2-2 & \text { otherwise }\end{cases}
     ^
ParseFatalException: Unknown symbol: \begin, found '\'  (at char 5), (line:1, col:6)

It seems like Matplotlib has trouble parsing the \begin{cases} structure in the second formula. How can I fix this error? Is there a specific format I need to follow for cases in LaTeX with Matplotlib?
Thank you for your help!

By default Matplotlib uses its own module to parse the latex formulae, but it has not implemented everything.  You can instead get it to use your Latex installation to parse them https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/text/usetex.html#usetex

@RuthC: got it! Now it works, thank you very much!
